# Button not responding to font-family declaration in css

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-family

I have a button, and a corresponding CSS declaration to change its `font-family`, but the button's font doesn't change.

This is the reasearch I've conducted:

I had found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21381909/font-family-does-not-change-in-the-output), but it was not answered, and I had already used `!important`, and checked devtools, but devtools said that it was applying the font. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31438461/font-family-declaration-doesnt-work) doesn't apply to me: I'm not using any form of `reset.css`. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50773591/changing-html-button-font-with-css) also doesn't apply to me, as he/she made a mistake with the declaration, and that was about inputs, not buttons.

This is the code that styles the button:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis');

/* ... */

button.main {
  width: 40%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-top: 20px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 50px;
  border-style: solid;
  background-color: #50c878;
  border-color: #60b989;
}

button {
  font-family: "Dosis" !important;
}
```

I expected the button to have the Dosis font, but it instead has the default font. I can't seem to find any errors in it.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Is the font working at all? Do other elements show the font? It seems to work in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/Ly9znoxg/).

Comment: Yes, and I realised that I made a dumb, idiotic mistake. Turns out, the font I selected looks a decent bit like the normal, especially when it isn't bold, so this whole time it *was* working, just I couldn't tell the difference.

Comment: Ah, glad it's solved then!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the font I selected looks a decent bit like the normal, especially when it isn't bold, so this whole time it *was* working, just I couldn't tell the difference.

Sorry!